# possibilities for except (python, crawler)

Tags: python

i'm an absolut beginner, but with youtube and some websites i've written a crawler for the german website Immoscout24.

My problem: the crawler works fine, if all attributes are excisting. But if one site hasn't any attribute (e.g. "pre" in "beschreibung_container"), i'll get "NameError: name 'beschreibung' is not defined". How can i do, that it writes nothing ("") into my result list (csv), if the attribute not exists ans continues crawling?

```
for number in numbers:
my_url = "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/%s#/" %number

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"id":"is24-content"})

filename = "results_"+current_datetime+".csv"
f = open(filename, "a")

headers = "Objekt-ID##Titel##Adresse##Merkmale##Kosten##Bausubstanz und Energieausweis##Beschreibung##Ausstattung##Lage\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    try:
        objektid_container = container.find_all("div", {"class":"is24-scoutid__content padding-top-s"})
        objektid = objektid_container[0].get_text().strip()

        titel_container = container.find_all("h1", {"class":"font-semibold font-xl margin-bottom margin-top-m palm-font-l"})
        titel = titel_container[0].get_text().strip()

        adresse_container = container.find_all("div", {"class":"address-block"})
        adresse = adresse_container[0].get_text().strip()

        criteria_container = container.find_all("div", {"class":"criteriagroup criteria-group--two-columns"})
        criteria = criteria_container[0].get_text().strip()

        preis_container = container.find_all("div", {"class":"grid-item lap-one-half desk-one-half padding-right-s"})
        preis = preis_container[0].get_text().strip()

        energie_container = container.find_all("div", {"class":"criteriagroup criteria-group--border criteria-group--two-columns criteria-group--spacing"})
        energie = energie_container[0].get_text().strip()

        beschreibung_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-objektbeschreibung text-content short-text"})
        beschreibung = beschreibung_container[0].get_text().strip()

        ausstattung_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-ausstattung text-content short-text"})
        ausstattung = ausstattung_container[0].get_text().strip()

        lage_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-lage text-content short-text"})
        lage = lage_container[0].get_text().strip()
    except:
        print("some mistake")
        pass

f.write(objektid + "##" + titel + "##" + adresse + "##" + criteria.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + preis.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + energie.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + beschreibung.replace("\n", " ") + "##" + ausstattung.replace("\n", " ") + "##" + lage.replace("\n", " ") + "\n")

f.close()
```

**EDIT**

First problem is solved. Another problem: my result list shows in each column like:
[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnPZi.png)

How can i do, that "Objekt-ID" and the other headlines are only in row No. 1?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to add try except for each variable instead of just one for all

Comment: The output you showed is this csv file? can you open csv file in notepad and see if its generating correctly?

Comment: So you want the output to be in a table format is it?

Comment: yes i showed the csv. if i'll open with wordpad (i haven't anymore notepad) it is the same. each second row are the headlines from headers.

Comment: the table format isn't the problem i think. Only that i have the same content (headlines) in each second row instead of only in the first row.

Comment: Your example and question isn't very clear. Can you rephrase it or give better example?

Comment: @JuliGoe Please show updated code, it seems you are writing headers inside loop

Comment: i've add a picture. I'll hope it's clear now.

Comment: @JuliGoe updated my Answer please check

Comment: @madforstrength: I think you're right. The code isn't edited except your adviced code (and in a second file Thu Yein Tuns code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each variable, you can simply just do the following

```
obj = container.find_all("div", {"class":"xxxxx"}) or ""
objid = obj[0].get_text().strip() if obj else ""
```

The first line will default the value into `""` empty string if find_all returns empty list or none. The second also does the same thing but check for the existence of value first then apply the if else condition.

Comment: it also works fine. You know which variant works faster?

Comment: OR operation in many programming languages is usually just 1 CPU instruction. So this *may* be faster than waiting for the exception to be raised. I would prefer this method due to it's cleanliness. The other way is to encapsulate `try except` for every single variables, which leads to ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to encapsulate each variable in try-except block.

E.g:

```
try:
    objektid_container = container.find_all("div", {"class":"is24-scoutid__content padding-top-s"})
    objektid = objektid_container[0].get_text().strip()
except:
    objektid = ""
```

Do this for all variables

For Second issue Move your headers outside loop
Remove this code:

```
filename = "results_"+current_datetime+".csv"
f = open(filename, "a")

headers = "Objekt-ID##Titel##Adresse##Merkmale##Kosten##Bausubstanz und Energieausweis##Beschreibung##Ausstattung##Lage\n"

f.write(headers)
```

And add it before:

```
for number in numbers:
```

Comment: oh that's really simple and it works. Thanks. I forgot another question. I'll edit my question. Maybe you can help me again.

Comment: maybe i'm too stupid, but it doesn't works. But if it's a bit difficult, i can leave off the headline.

Comment: @JuliGoe: What do you mean by doesnt work, did you get any error?

Comment: now it works. I've done a mistake with the indents (blanks?). Thanks really much.